# How do i add the Google Trusted Store badge to ASPdotnetstorefront

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net, html

how do I add the trusted badge scripts to aspdotnetstorefront? Google requires the code below to be places in the ordersconfirmation page, most likely ordersconfirmation.aspx. How do I access the source code of the page implement the code to the site with the correct variables? Thanks!

```
<!-- START Trusted Stores Order -->
<div id="gts-order" style="display:none;">

  <!-- start order and merchant information -->
  <span id="gts-o-id">MERCHANT_ORDER_ID</span>
  <span id="gts-o-domain">MERCHANT_ORDER_DOMAIN</span>
  <span id="gts-o-email">CUSTOMER_EMAIL</span>
  <span id="gts-o-country">CUSTOMER_COUNTRY</span>
  <span id="gts-o-currency">CURRENCY</span>
  <span id="gts-o-total">ORDER_TOTAL</span>
  <span id="gts-o-discounts">ORDER_DISCOUNTS</span>
  <span id="gts-o-shipping-total">ORDER_SHIPPING</span>
  <span id="gts-o-tax-total">ORDER_TAX</span>
  <span id="gts-o-est-ship-date">ORDER_EST_SHIP_DATE</span>
  <span id="gts-o-has-preorder">HAS_BACKORDER_PREORDER</span>
  <span id="gts-o-has-digital">HAS_DIGITAL_GOODS</span>
  <!-- end order and merchant information -->

  <!-- start repeated item specific information -->
  <!-- item example: this area repeated for each item in the order -->
  <span class="gts-item">
    <span class="gts-i-name">ITEM_NAME</span>
    <span class="gts-i-price">ITEM_PRICE</span>
    <span class="gts-i-quantity">ITEM_QUANTITY</span>
    <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-id">ITEM_PRODUCT_SEARCH_ID</span>
    <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-store-id">ITEM_PRODUCT_SEARCH_ACCOUNT_ID</span>
    <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-country">ITEM_PRODUCT_SEARCH_COUNTRY</span>
    <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-language">ITEM_PRODUCT_SEARCH_LANGUAGE</span>
  </span>
  <!-- end item 1 example -->
  <!-- end repeated item specific information -->

</div>
<!-- END Trusted Stores -->
```

heres [Link to google trusted store](https://support.google.com/trustedstoresmerchant/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2609894&ctx=go#Section2) to get a better idea of what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, you will need to make those insertions to the code behind file. If you have the C# solution, the file you are looking for is orderconfirmation.aspx.cs, if VB, orderconfirmation.aspx.vb. If you have not already, I suggest setting up a local ASPDNS solution, so that you can make and test the code changes before uploading to your web server.

Note: Depending on how your solution is setup, executing the changes may vary (for example a precompiled site), or may not be possible (for example, if you are a ChannelAdvisor client).

Comment: I do have access to the orderconfirmation.aspx.cs, Is it possible from there I can add the Code that is shown from on the post?

Comment: This may be worth checking out: http://www.aspdotnetstorefront.com/p-759-google-trusted-stores-for-aspdotnetstorefront.aspx